# How can I install extension of vscode?

Tags: nixos, nixpkgs

This is a beginner question. So there is a package `vscode-with-extensions`. 
The [package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/editors/vscode/with-extensions.nix) says:

> A set of vscode extensions to be installed alongside the editor. Here's a an example:

```
vscode-with-extensions.override {
  # When the extension is already available in the default extensions set.
  vscodeExtensions = with vscode-extensions; [
    bbenoist.Nix
  ]
  # Concise version from the vscode market place when not available in the default set.
  ++ vscode-utils.extensionsFromVscodeMarketplace [
    {
      name = "code-runner";
      publisher = "formulahendry";
      version = "0.6.33";
      sha256 = "166ia73vrcl5c9hm4q1a73qdn56m0jc7flfsk5p5q41na9f10lb0";
    }
  ];
}
```

Where in `configuration.nix` do I have to put this expression? I already have

```
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
     wget 
     vim 
     vscode-with-extensions
  ];
```

therein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re supposed to use it as in the configuration.nix directly, like for instance

```
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
     wget 
     vim 
     (vscode-with-extensions.override {
  # When the extension is already available in the default extensions set.
  vscodeExtensions = with vscode-extensions; [
    bbenoist.Nix
  ]
  # Concise version from the vscode market place when not available in the default set.
  ++ vscode-utils.extensionsFromVscodeMarketplace [
    {
      name = "code-runner";
      publisher = "formulahendry";
      version = "0.6.33";
      sha256 = "166ia73vrcl5c9hm4q1a73qdn56m0jc7flfsk5p5q41na9f10lb0";
    }
  ];
})
  ];
```

Or, in a more readable version:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs;
  let
    vcsodeWithExtension = vscode-with-extensions.override {
      # When the extension is already available in the default extensions set.
      vscodeExtensions = with vscode-extensions; [
        bbenoist.Nix
      ]
      # Concise version from the vscode market place when not available in the default set.
      ++ vscode-utils.extensionsFromVscodeMarketplace [
        {
          name = "code-runner";
          publisher = "formulahendry";
          version = "0.6.33";
          sha256 = "166ia73vrcl5c9hm4q1a73qdn56m0jc7flfsk5p5q41na9f10lb0";
        }
      ];
    })
  in
    [
      wget
      vim
      vcsodeWithExtension
    ];
```

Comment: Where do I get the sha256 from?

Comment: The usual way is to put a random string there ("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000") and let nix complain about it, and it will tell you the actual computed one

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently it can go directly into `environment.systemPackages`, but requires parentheses:

```
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    wget 
    vim 
    (vscode-with-extensions.override {
      vscodeExtensions = with vscode-extensions; [
        bbenoist.Nix
      ];
    })
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using nix ... installed nixos. I came across this problem also (trying to get vscode installed with this extensions mechanism, but with a slightly different set of extensions and not wanting to pollute my base machine with a vscode install). The solution that worked for me, using the `nix-shell` command via the terminal console to create a reproducible environment. After running `nix-shell` the command `code .` successfully started vscode:

- needed to create a file config.nix in the directory `~/.config/nixpkgs/` with the contents:

```
{ allowUnfree = true; }
```

- in a console, in a directory with a `shell.nix` file in it with the following code that configures vscode using this extensions mechanism:

```
{ pkgs ? import (fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/50c23cd4ff6c8344e0b4d438b027b3afabfe58dd.tar.gz") {} }:

let vscodeWithExtension = (pkgs.vscode-with-extensions.override {
        vscodeExtensions = with pkgs.vscode-extensions; [
              bbenoist.nix
              ms-python.python
              ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
              ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
            ] ++ pkgs.vscode-utils.extensionsFromVscodeMarketplace [
              {
                name = "remote-ssh-edit";
                publisher = "ms-vscode-remote";
                version = "0.47.2";
                sha256 = "1hp6gjh4xp2m1xlm1jsdzxw9d8frkiidhph6nvl24d0h8z34w49g";
              }
            ];
          }
    );
in
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.git
    pkgs.ghc
    pkgs.ghcid
    vscodeWithExtension
  ];

  shellHook = ''
    echo hello ghc
  '';

  MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = "world";
}
```